# Pausing and resuming a transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am using `setInterval`, so transitions take place after a certain interval. Is it possible to get pausing and resuming to work with setInterval?

Any suggestions/pointers in the right direction will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/)?

Comment: Yeah I did see the article but I am not sure how it will work with setInterval function which has a certain time interval specified. I have transitions starting after a certain interval and once the visualisation is complete, I have used clearInterval. Is it even possible to get pause and resume functions to work with setInterval? Or will it will require me to change the implementation?

Comment: In principle you should be able to use `setInterval` without problems.

Comment: Could you tell why you need to use interval? Will `.delay` and 'on start' handler to create repeat function with d3.active not do? [example](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active)

Answer (score 4):

This question was posted when D3 v3 was the latest version available. 5 years later D3 v5 has some new methods, like [`selection.interrupt()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#selection_interrupt), [`transition.on("interrupt"...)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_on) and [`local variables`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local), which can make the task more simple and less painful.

So, let's suppose a simple `cx` transition on a circle:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cx", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .style("fill", "teal")
  .style("stroke", "black");
circle.transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr("cx", 580);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: block;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

The idea is interrupting the transition when, for instance, a button is pressed:

```
selection.interrupt();
```

And then, with a local variable, use the listener for `interrupt` to get the current position:

```
.on("interrupt", function() {
    local.set(this, +d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
});
```

Finally, when the button is pressed again, we use `local.get(this)` and a simple math to get the remaining `duration`.

It's also worth mentioning that this works for linear easing; if you have another easing, like the default `d3.easeCubic`, you'll need a way more complex code.

And here is the demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const local = d3.local();
const button = d3.select("button");
const circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("cx", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .style("fill", "teal")
  .style("stroke", "black");
circle.transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr("cx", 580)
  .on("interrupt", function() {
    local.set(this, +d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
  });
button.on("click", function() {
  if (d3.active(circle.node())) {
    circle.interrupt();
    this.textContent = "Resume";
  } else {
    circle.transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(function() {
        return 10000 * (560 - local.get(this)) / 560;
      })
      .attr("cx", 580)
    this.textContent = "Stop";
  }
})
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: block;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Stop</button>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: You are quite good, can you please tell me why 560 and not 580 in `cx`?

Comment: @yavg that's probably a typo.