# d3 how to start a interrupt transition

Tags: d3.js

I use d3 4.X in my project. Does anybody know how to start an interrupt transition?

```
circle.transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(10000)
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to be more precise in your question: explain what are you trying to achieve, what you have done so far and what problem you are currently facing/what error message you get.

Comment: Are you asking how to pause and resume a transition? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23048263/7106086) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47350645/7106086)